# What is the best practice to saving your game in Dying Light?

Tags: dying-light

The saving system in Dying Light is very confusing, after leaving the game in a save zone, you can find yourself in the middle of the city at midnight after loading that game again.

Is there any 100% practice to save your game?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Going through a door which loads a new area is what I use.

The most obvious door is the elevator in the tower to go up to the 19th floor. So when I want to quit the game I usually make my way back to the tower and then take the lift.

The save happens before loading the new area. So you will start on the ground floor of the tower.

Answer (score 4):

Go into your Online settings. Change any of the settings there and change it back again. It triggers an autosave. This allows you to save your game ANYWHERE in the game. Even if you don't have internet, just switch from Single Player to Public and back to Single Player. You will see the auto save symbol pop up in the bottom right corner of the screen. You're welcome :)

Comment: "You will see the auto save symbol pop up in the bottom right corner of the screen." Doesn't happen for me. Makes no difference at all.